# Nested table won't update when using accepts_nested_attributes_for method in Rails 5.0, Ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get two tables to update simultaneously after clicking "Submit" in a form. There is a "workouts" table and an "exercises" table; a workout has_many exercises. For some reason right now when clicking "Submit" on the form, only the "workouts" table gets updated and not the "exercises" table. Below is the controller, view, and models. I am using Ruby 2.3, Rails 5.0 and a Windows PC.

Workouts Controller (workouts_controller.rb)

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController    
def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.exercises.build
end

def create
    @workout = Workout.create(workout_params)
    if @workout.save
        redirect_to @workout
    end
end

def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
    @exercises = @workout.exercises
end

private
    def workout_params
        params.require(:workout).permit(:workout_length, :workout_description, :video_url, exercises_attributes: [:exercise_description])
    end
end
```

New Workout View (workouts\new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Create New Workout</h1>

<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :workout_length, :placeholder => "Workout length (minutes)" %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :workout_description, :placeholder => "Workout description" %> <br>
  <%= f.url_field :video_url, :placeholder => "Video URL" %> <br>

  <%= fields_for :exercises do |builder| %>
    <p>
    <%= builder.label :exercise_description %>
    <%= builder.text_field :exercise_description %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT WORKOUT"  %>
<% end %>
```

Workout model (workout.rb)

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exercises, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
    validates_associated :exercises
end
```

Exercise model (exercise.rb)

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :workout
end
```

Workout migration (_create_workouts.rb)

```
class CreateWorkouts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :workouts do |t|
      t.integer :workout_length
      t.string :workout_description
      t.string :video_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Exercise migration (_create_exercises.rb)

```
class CreateExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :exercises do |t|
      t.string :exercise_description
      t.references :workout, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

After I submit the form, the "workouts" table gets updated via an INSERT statement as expected, but the "exercises" table does not have any new rows...no INSERT statement is executed for "exercises". Any ideas on why the "exercises" table is not getting updated???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing `fields_for` for nested attributes, you have to use the `fields_for` method that belongs to the higher-level form object.

So instead of doing...

```
<%= fields_for :exercises do |builder| %>
```

do...

```
<%= f.fields_for :exercises do |builder| %>
```

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn! That makes sense. I made that change but I'm still not getting the second table to update...I'm getting an error that says "Unpermitted parameter: exercises_attributes". I assume this is in my workout_params private function, but I can't seem to get that to work...

Comment: Huh.  I dunno.  The spelling of `exercises_attributes` in the `workout_params` matches exactly the spelling on the error message?

Comment: I slightly modified the workout params and now I'm getting a message that says "No template found for WorkoutsController#create, rendering head :no_content". I'm not having much luck :(

Comment: So now that I'm no longer having issues with the params, I am confused as to why rails needs a WorkoutsController#create template...why can't I just POST to both tables?

Comment: You don't need a template for create unless you fail to render or redirect.  Most typical rails Create controllers look like `def create; @workout = Workout.new; if @workout.update_attributes(workout_params);redirect_to @workout; else; render :new; end; end`  You're missing the "if it doesn't save properly" bit... the `else` and `render :new` bit, so it falls through and expects there must be a create template to render.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you. Is there a way to debug and see exactly why the POST is failing to save in the first place?

Comment: Sure, add 'pry' to your project Gemfile, include the line ...`group :development { gem 'pry' }`  Then in your controller after the `else` line for failure add `binding.pry`   and then run the rails server `rails s` and do the action to create the object. When processing halts, you can examine the object interactively... type `@workout.valid?` and `@workout.errors.full_messages`  and when you're ready to resume processing type `exit`

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help @SteveTurczyn! I can tell PRY will be a useful tool in the future for me. I used pry and submit the form, then when I ran `@workout.errors.full_messages` the error reads "Exercises workout must exist". Any thoughts on what that might mean?

Comment: That's from the validates_associated...  Comment that line out and see how far you get.

Comment: I got rid of `validates_associated` and I'm still getting the "Exercises workout must exist" error :(

Comment: I actually got it to work by adding `belongs_to :workout, required: false` in the Exercises controller.

Comment: Ah, cool... although I always thought `required: false` was the default so i'm not sure that was it... but if it's working, that's good.